# Slack python client uploading blank files

Tags: python, slack

I'm using the following python/slack_sdk code to upload a series of files to a slack channel:

```
from slack_sdk import WebClient

WebClient(token=os.getenv('SLACK_LOGGING_BOT_TOKEN')).files_upload_v2(channel=channel_id,initial_comment=initial_comment,file=file_name)
```

Uploading works, the problem is that sometimes one or multiple of those files are showing up blank (like in the picture attached) on slack but I'm 100% sure they are populated
[image: blank file]

This one is a csv file like the following:
| Statistic          | Value          |
| ------------------ | -------------- |
| Signups            |  24            |
| Churns             |  14            |
| Net Activations    |  10            |

If I download the file from slack is also empty.

I can't even consistently reproduce the bug so I don't know how to solve it. Any ideas of what is going on?

Comment: Went to github and posted the same question: https://github.com/slackapi/python-slack-sdk/issues/1404#issuecomment-1731412479

Comment: Update: this is a slack bug, this is happening from the slack client as well. Per the github issue they are looking into it